# Convert Map Coordinates to Coordinate System

Tags: java, google-maps, dictionary, coordinates

I have a list of addresses/GPS-coordinates which I need to convert into a coordinate system, so that the distances between the points don't equal the air-line distance but the travel distance (in time) between the points.

So I'd need to get the travel time between all the addresses (e.g. through the google maps API) and then somehow create a coordinate system with this data.

So my first question is: Is it at all possible to get the travel time between all the addresses if I have like 50 addresses, or does this take far too long? I mean it doesn't need to be through google maps API, I could also do it through offline maps data.

And the second question: How to create such a coordinate system? Is there some kind of a name for this problem so I can google it? I just don't know what to search...

Comment: I don't understand one thing. What is the coordinate system stated in first sentence of question? GPS-coordinates are indeed already a coordinate system.

Comment: Sorry this is hard to explain. The distance between GPS-coordinates is the air-line distance, right? But I want to convert the coordinates so that the distance between them aren't the air-line but the travel time.
e.g. the GPS-coordinates distance between new york and washington d.c. would be 213 (miles) but I want to convert the coordinates so that the distance would be 223 (minutes). Hope this gets more clear now.

Comment: It's clear now. If u have 50 cities (points) and you want to compute distance between all of them then it is basically 1225 calls to imaginary function getDistanceInMinutes(point a, point b) . It's not that much IMO.
I don't see a problem from your second question unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure your overall goal with this, but the Google Maps API has a specific [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests) which allows you to make requests using well-formed URL-queries with parameters that yield results in JSON format, which  aren't too difficult to parse through.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, there are N geographic locations whose distances in time are known. The intention is to draw a two-dimensional map where the distances on paper would represent the travel distances.

This is an interesting approach, because this is how we usually perceive distances, and a map done this way would be more intuitive than the dull ordinary one.

Unfortunately, this task is unsolvable in the general case. To prove this I'll show an unsolvable case with just four points.

- there are two neighbouring cities A and B
- between these cities there are three suburbs C and D
- there are only four roads, which are between the cities and the suburbs (A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D)
- each road is equally long, and the travel takes 15 minutes

So, the travel from city A to city B takes 30 minutes (either via C or via D). The travel from either suburb to either city takes 15 minutes, and the travel between suburbs C and D takes 30 minutes (either via A or via B).

Now, because all roads take equal time, points A, C, B, and D must form a parallelogram with equal length (15 minutes) for all sides. Both diagonals AB and CD should have double length, as these distances are 30 minutes each. This is impossible, because if the diagonals have equal length, the length is sqrt(2) x 15 minutes and we have a square.